# How can i convert string datatype to date datatype in flex

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I have to convert one string type field to date datatype in flex.

What can I do solve this problem?

Comment: Have you had a chance to try the answer I posted? If it helps solve your problem, you can upvote it by clicking on the ^ arrow and flag it as the accepted answer by clicking on the check mark icon next to my answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
import mx.controls.DateField;

var dateString:String = " 25/02/2009";
var date:Date= DateField.stringToDate(dateString,"DD/MM/YYYY");
```

with credit to:
http://amthekkel.blogspot.com/2009/02/flex-converting-date-string-to-date.html

Answer (score 4):

```
var str:String = "25/02/2009"
var d:Date = new Date(str);
```

or

we can use a custom DateUtils class

```
package 
{
  import mx.formatters.DateFormatter;

  public class DateUtils extends DateFormatter
 {
    public function DateUtils()
   {
     super();
   }



  public static function parseString (str:String):Date {
      return parseDateString(str);
  }

 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `Date.parse` function with the `Date.setTime` function to create a new `Date` object from a string.

```
var myDateString:String = "05/10/2011";
var myDate:Date = new Date();

myDate.setTime(Date.parse(myDateString));
```